# running bib file does not generate bbl file

Tags: bibtex

I am taking the class "LaTeX for Professional Publications" on Udemy and I am unable to get my citations to work. I am using MikTeX with the TeXworks editor. Following the instructions from the class, I have created a file called `references.bib`:

```
@article{Linusson2013,
author = "Henrik Linusson",
title = "Multi-Output Random Forests",
journal = "University of Borås",
year = "2013"
}
```

I would like to cite the article in my LateX doc `article.tex`, as well as add a bibliography in the reference section:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}   
\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
This is an example of a LaTeX document with BibTex~\cite{Linusson2013}

\section{References}

\bibliography{references} 

\end{document}
```

Based on the instructions from the class, I first ran `references.bib` with BibTeX in order to generate a bbl file but that failed (error message says .aux file cannot be found). Naturally, the citations don't show in my article when I compile `article.tex` using pdfLaTeX. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: you don't run bibtex on the bib-file, call `bibtex article` instead (after your ran `pdflatex article`) and then call `pdflatex article` again twice.

Comment: Your tex file appears to be missing a `\bibliographystyle` instruction. Without such a directive, BibTeX doesn't know what to do and therefore outputs nothing at all.

Comment: I'd say you need to seriously critique the course for its lack of proper instructions on how to use BibTeX.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There appear to be two issues with your approach to generating a bibliography and citation call-outs.

- The tex file is missing a `\bibliographystyle` instruction. The argument of `\bibliographystyle` contains the style that is to be implemented. This is an essential directive; without it, BibTeX will generate no output at all.
- It is simply misguided and misleading to say that one "runs [a bib file] with BibTeX". The bib file is an essential input for BibTeX, but it's only one of *several* inputs.

  If the main tex file is called `mywork.tex`, say, then one needs to run

  ```
  bibtex mywork
  ```

  BibTeX will inspect the file `mywork.aux` (which is created by an earlier LaTeX run) for information about the bibliography style to be adhered to, the items that were `\cite`d, and the bib file(s) that contain the cited entries. Based on these pieces of information, it will create a file called `mywork.bbl` (the formatted bib entries) and `mywork.blg`, the associate log file. If there are any syntax errors in the bib file, you'll find out about it in the blg log file.

The workflow therefore is:

```
pdflatex mywork
bibtex mywork
pdflatex mywork
pdflatex mywork
```

Note that it's necessary to run LaTeX *twice more* after the BibTeX run in order to fully propagate all changes.

An MWE (minimum working example) -- observe that I've chosen the `plain` bibliography style; you should choose a style that meets your formatting needs.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{myreferences.bib}
@misc{Linusson2013,
   author  = "Henrik Linusson",
   title   = "Multi-Output Random Forests",
   howpublished = "University of Borås",
   year    = "2013",
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\bibliographystyle{plain}  % <-- choose a suitable bib style
\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
This is an example of a \LaTeX\ document with a bibliography and citation call-outs generated by Bib\TeX~\cite{Linusson2013}.

\bibliography{myreferences} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: I want to point out here that the `documentclass` is very important. I was trying to use citations with `standalone` and getting non-informative errors. I tried changing the `documentclass` to match this one here and it works!

Comment: @Breedly - Indeed, the choice of document class is hugely important. IMNSHO, the `standalone` document class is suitable only for single items such as `figure`, `table`, and`equation` environments, whose pdf or png formats are intended for use in an external document such as a powerpoint file.